# Cauchy Integral Formula Question $\int_{C(2,1)} (z^4-\frac 1 z)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm looking to compute the following integral

$$\int_{C(2,1)} (z^4-\frac 1 z)dz$$.

My question here is does Cauchy’s Integral Formula hold or even apply here?

Is $f(z)=(z^4-\frac 1 z)$ entire and therefore diﬀerentiable on $D(2,1 + \epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

If so my answer would just simply be $I = 2\pi i f(i) = 2\pi i(1-\frac 1 i) = 2\pi i - 2\pi$

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What is $C(2,1)$?

Comment: Just to be a bit neat: what does $C(2,1)$  mean? $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=0$. We shall check if 0 is inside your domain. So, we can apply the Cauchy integral formula, for instane.

Comment: That is part of my confusion also. The question just states that it is a contour integral. So I presume it is a circle enclosed within the disc D.

Comment: Are you talking about the circle centered at $2$ with radius $1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the disk centered at $2$ with radius $1$ is simply connected and it is contained in the domain of $z^4-\dfrac1z$, Cauchy's integral theorem tells us that that integral is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is analytic on the disk of radius $1$ centered at $2$.  Thus by Cauchy's theorem, the integral is zero.

If instead you take a closed contour enclosing zero, you get $-2\pi i$, since $z^4$ is entire and $1/z$ has a simple pole.

Comment: How do you identify that it is analytic so quickly. Is there further background calculations to this is or is it just easily identified for you?

Comment: Easy to see that other than zero, where there's a pole, it's analytic.